# Is it true that all PE binary size is a multiple of 256 bytes?

Tags: windows

I reviewed the size of two PE binary,both are a multiple of 256 bytes, but I'm not sure if it's the PE standard, or only hold in windows?

Comment: To satisfy the curious, "PE" is ["Portable Executable"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot find any indication on the web that a PE binary has to be a multiple of 256 bytes, and this seems higly unlikely.

As a counter point, I've had a look at the `excel.exe` on my current machine (from Office 2003) which disproves this theory.

**Filesize:**
10 095 808 (9.62MiB)
Not divisble by 256 (divison results in 39436.75).

**PE Binary? Yes:**
Starts with **MZ** identifier, first line (reading in notepad!) contains the expected `This program cannot be run in DOS mode.` string. This section is here to safely deflect DOS (as in DOS itself, not the windows command line) from running the binary without crashing.

Contains the **PE** identifier at about byte 295 (again, reading in notepad, please excuse any inaccuracy). This is where execution will start in all compatible OSes.

<sub>**PS:** Most (all?) 32-bit executables on modern Windows are in PE format.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

*Size* or *Size on Disk*?

**Size** is the number of bytes the file actually contains.

**Size on Disk** is the number of bytes the file has to use up on your drive. This is normally larger, because it has to round up to a multiple of the *cluster size* (alternatively called *allocation unit*) of that partition / disk. This will normally be a multiple of your disk's sector size, which is normally 512 bytes for most modern magnetic HDDs.

Cluster size is most commonly 4KiB *by default* - depending on OS, file system and disk size - but you can usually define the size used when formatting the disk/partition.
Check this [Microsoft KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140365) for info on default sizes in most of their OSes.

This means a 1 byte file will have to use up the size of 1 whole cluster, because a cluster may only contain a single file, regardless of if that file only takes up a tiny portion of the cluster.

Comment: I mean Size,not Size on Disk.And I'm talking about PE binary in windows.

Comment: What *type* of file you are talking about wouldn't matter, what I've said holds true for *all* files, although not relevant it seems in this case. I highly doubt that the file format requires a size to be a multiple of 256, but I am unable to find a source to back me up at the moment.

Comment: After a quick web search I can't find any indication of this being a restriction on the file size. As a quick counter point I've just been looking at my Office 2003 `excel.exe`, it is 10095808 bytes large - or 9.62MiB - and *not* evenly divisable by 256. It has the `MZ` identifer as it's first to chars and the identifier `PE` is there at *about* byte 295 (was reading with notepad; not the *best* tool for the job, please excuse the inaccuracy) so I'm pretty sure it's a PE binary, I'd be surprised if it's not.